# Query para soma do valor total

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, pl-sql

Questão: Criar uma Query que produza um relatório com os seguintes itens:

- a) Nome do cliente;
- b) Valor total do pedido;
- c) Ordenação por data (decrescente) e maior valor (decrescente);

Minha dificuldade está em realizar a soma do valor total por pedido, visto que o `id_pedido` se repete em mais de um item (ex.: ID_pedido = 1, valor_produto =5; ID_produto = 1, valor_pedido 3), havendo a necessidade de somá-los para se chegar ao valor total por `id_pedido`. Tudo deve ocorrer dentro do SELECT.

```
SELECT pe.id_pedido, C.NOME_CLIENTE, PE.DATA_PEDIDO, P.VALOR_PRODUTO * IP.QUANTIDADE AS TOTAL_PED
FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN PEDIDOS PE
ON c.id_cliente = pe.id_cliente
INNER JOIN ITEM_PEDIDOS IP
ON pe.id_pedido = ip.id_pedido
INNER JOIN produtos P
ON ip.id_produto = p.id_produto
ORDER BY pe.data_pedido, pe.id_pedido DESC;
```

---

[image: Resultado da query descrita acima]

Comment: *"Minha dificuldade está em realizar a soma do valor total por pedido, visto que o id_pedido se repete em mais de um item"* mas no enuncionado não pede o id, pode simplesmente remover ele do `SELECT`, ou não vai conseguir agrupar, agrupe só por nome e data

Comment: se eu entendi bem você quer agrupar os campos onde tem o mesmo `id_pedido` somando os valores deles, no caso do `id_pedido` = 20 o `TOTAL_PEDIDO` será igual a 23,61. Correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, esse é o objetivo!!

Comment: Já estudou o `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa agrupar pelo `id_pedido` e usar a função SUM para somar os campos que compõem o valor total do pedido

```sql
SELECT pe.id_pedido, C.NOME_CLIENTE, PE.DATA_PEDIDO, SUM(P.VALOR_PRODUTO * IP.QUANTIDADE) AS TOTAL_PED
FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN PEDIDOS PE
ON c.id_cliente = pe.id_cliente
INNER JOIN ITEM_PEDIDOS IP
ON pe.id_pedido = ip.id_pedido
INNER JOIN produtos P
ON ip.id_produto = p.id_produto
GROUP BY pe.id_pedido
ORDER BY pe.data_pedido, pe.id_pedido DESC;
```

Comment: Obrigada!! Perfeito! Fiz uma pequena alteração para o meu cenário e funcionou, conforme sua orientação: 

SELECT pe.id_pedido, C.NOME_CLIENTE, PE.DATA_PEDIDO, SUM(P.VALOR_PRODUTO * IP.QUANTIDADE) AS TOTAL_PED
FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN PEDIDOS PE
ON c.id_cliente = pe.id_cliente
INNER JOIN ITEM_PEDIDOS IP
ON pe.id_pedido = ip.id_pedido
INNER JOIN produtos P
ON ip.id_produto = p.id_produto
GROUP BY pe.id_pedido, C.NOME_CLIENTE, PE.DATA_PEDIDO;

Comment: Por nada ! Considere aceitar a resposta como solução da sua pergunta @Bia.mts!